# Rest Api design: resource archetypes, store and controller

Tags: java, api, rest

i am currently in the process of looking more closely at the design of truly restful services.During my research I read something about resource archetypes at rest, four different types of archetypes come up frequently in discussion: document, collection, memory and controller.  The first two I understand without any problems, but the last two I don't really understand. Can someone please give a clear explanation and example for both? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are four main archetypes at rest, the two that you're asking are:

1. Store: It'll never generate a new URI, we'll use the next URI `http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlists` a user can PUT, GET and DELETE any playlist from its account but this store, the store is always managed by the client.
2. Controller: Are like functions, when HTTP verbs can't say the action which a resource will do, you should use this archetype. Eg. `http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlist/play` will starts a playlist.

resource: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: Thx for your explanation.